# Screenshooter hangs XFCE4

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, freeze, screenshot

Several times over the last 48 hours I have had to reboot my way out of an XFCE4 hang where the mouse and keyboard cease responding in the GUI.

A pattern has emerged whereby this happens just after I have taken a screenshot using `xfce4-screenshooter`.

On @aquaherd's advice I found that `sudo service lightdm restart` did at least remove the need for a full reboot.

Is there any way I can fix this problem ?

**Original Question**

Several times over the last 24 hours I have had to reboot my way out of an XFCE4 hang where the mouse and keyboard cease responding in the GUI.

When this happens I am able to use `ctrl`-`alt`-`f1` to get to TTY1 and I can login there by any attempt to bring xfce down (such as `xfwm4 --replace`, `xfce4-session-logout` or `sudo service dbus restart`) ultimately results in me having to issue a reboot command.

I've seen some indication that the hang might be dbus related (sorry I didn't take a specific note).

Also I think both of the latest problems have occurred within a few seconds of me taking a screenshot.

I would like suggestions on what I can do to pin the problem down and fix it.

Thanks

Comment: On the console, using `top` to find out if an application consumes all CPU or memory, viewing `~/.xsession-errors`, `dmesg` output and using `sudo service lightdm restart` as last measure comes to mind.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @aquaherd.  Interestingly I had tried restarting lightdm but that achieved nothing.  Anyway, I've written your suggestions down so next time it happens I've got something to start on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly old, but I thought I'd reopen this, with a possible but report in the making.

I oversee a fairly large network on which we have many users who access a central LTSP server. Lately, we've noticed slowdowns and unintended log-offs when users take screenshots. Looking at `top -0 %MEM`, there are some xfce4-screenshooter processes taking fairly little CPU resources, but significant fractions of a TiB of memory (0.19) one process hit, which appear to hang as they acquire lots and lots of CPU time. I haven't reproduced the problem myself yet (hence no bug report), but I'm about to confirm and thought I'd reopen this as a prelude to an xfce bug report.

In answer to the question, if you are able to open a terminal window:

```
ps -ef | grep xfce
```

will give you the PID of the xfce4-screenshooter process, which you can then kill:

```
sudo kill <pid>
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like this was already [solved](https://bbs.linuxdistrocommunity.com/discussion/592/how-to-fix-screenshot-freeze-bug-in-1-0-2).

Go to `~/.config/xfce4` and delete the `xfce4-screenshooter` file